# How can I make a user out of a model in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

I'm currently developing a web-application for managing driving licenses as a web development homework assignment. Instead of just storing information on every driver as a model I want to make a user for each driver. What is the easiest way to do so? What am I doing wrong?

I updated a car owner model so that it is now inherited from djangdo Abstract User.

```
# models.py

class Car_owner(AbstractUser):
    id_owner = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    passport = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)

    # username = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, default=uuid4)
    # password = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='password')
```

I also have forms.py file:

```
from django import forms
from project_first_app.models import Car_owner


class CreateOwner(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car_owner
        fields = ['id_owner', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'birth_date', 'passport', 'address', 'nationality']
```

But when migrating I get the following issue:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: new__project_first_app_car_owner.username
```

In migrations files I have:

```
 migrations.AddField(
            model_name='car_owner',
            name='username',
            field=models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, max_length=16, unique=True),
        ),
```

and then:

```
migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='car_owner',
            name='username',
            field=models.CharField(error_messages={'unique': 'A user with that username already exists.'}, help_text='Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', max_length=150, unique=True, validators=[django.contrib.auth.validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()], verbose_name='username'),
        ),
```

Those are automatically generated.

Comment: If you are getting the error when you are trying to migrate, then you have to deletr all the file in your migrations folder except **__init__.py**, drop database and then re-run migration.

Answer (score 1):

You have commented username and password in your model, why ?

Password field already exists in the abstractbaseuser, so comment it does not remove it. The abstract model user of Django need a unique information for authenticating user. You can use a Username or an Email.

For using the email instead of username, you can define `USERNAME_FIELD = "email"` in your class. But you have to define a field email, or you keep username field and add it to fields ModelForm.

There is a constraint on the username field (or email field), so you have to define it for each Car_owner you want to create (it is for authenticating purpose).

your field id_owner is useless, Django create automatically a field called `id` in each model which is the primary key.

so for resolving your problem easily, add username in fields list of your Form for beginning.